# Decode function inside a decode function oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement wherein I have to execute this query `(SUBSTR(sct.state_customer_type,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')+1,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,')')-INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')-1))` when user selects English language and if the language is selected as Spanish then execute this query `(SUBSTR(sct.state_customer_type,1,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')-1))`.
The language id would also come dynamically.
How can I write decode inside another decode function.

Thank you for your replies in advance.

Comment: It would be simpler to have the English and Spanish values in separate columns, or in a look-up table (particularly if you might add more languages), rather than embedding them in a strnig and having to parse them out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any decode functions in your code, but if your language id variable is `v_lang`, you could write:

```
select decode(v_lang,
    'English', 
        (SUBSTR(sct.state_customer_type,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')+1,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,')')-INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')-1)),
    'Spanish',
        (SUBSTR(sct.state_customer_type,1,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')-1)),
    null -- if v_lang is something else
    )
from ....
where ....
```

However, these days we recommend using ANSI `CASE` statements instead of `decode`. It's similar but easier to read and more portable.

```
select CASE v_lang
    WHEN 'English'
    THEN (SUBSTR(sct.state_customer_type,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')+1,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,')')-INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')-1))
    WHEN 'Spanish'
    THEN (SUBSTR(sct.state_customer_type,1,INSTR(sct.state_customer_type,'(')-1))
    ELSE null -- if v_lang is something else
    END
from ....
where ....
```